# How to ForwardAgent yes using fabric?

Tags: python, deployment, automation, fabric

I am successfully `run()`ning commands on remote server with my private key pair.

However, I'd like to do `git clone ssh://private/repo` on remote server using my local key (or using local ssh agent I'm in).

How to do it using fabric?

Comment: trying to figure this out right now too. keep you posted.

Comment: I just ended up added an additional key to my github account. Not ideal but okay for now.

Comment: Have you already tried editing `$HOME/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since version 1.4 `fabric` has [environment option](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/env.html?highlight=forwarding#forward-agent) that enables agent forwarding.

```
env.forward_agent = True
```

**UPD**: This feature [was buggy](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/562) before `fabric` 1.4.2

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that fabric uses a forked version of paramiko and that paramiko doesn't support ssh agent forwarding.

The long answer is that there are issues for this both for [fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/72) and [paramiko](https://github.com/robey/paramiko/pull/21). Even there's a [comment](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/72#issuecomment-2723351) in the fabric issue that contains links to a fork of both fabric and the forked paramiko version with ssh forwarding support. Hence, if you want to make use of that feature you'll need to get the latest version from there or wait for a while until it's officially released.

Comment: @ReducedGosling I haven't used fabric for quite a while. You might want to have a look at the `forward_agent` configuration value in the [documentation](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/concepts/configuration.html#new-default-values-defined-by-fabric).